# Is it possible to consistently apply voltage to two or more devices?

Tags: rpi.gpio, adafruit

I want to connect two or more of the following actuators to my raspberry pi:
https://www.ebay.com/itm/Nano-Magnetic-Actuator-diy-micro-plane-model-servo-micro-actuator-0-5g-/183745663278

However, most examples I have seen where multiple motors are controlled simultaneously using a servo driver such as the pca9685 involve alternating between the devices. If I were to connect two or more of the devices from the link above to it, would it be possible to simultaneously control all of their positions without running into problems such as overheating or the actuators constantly returning to their original position?

Comment: Hi @huehuehuehuehuehuehuehuehuehue, Ah let me see. PCA9685 alternates between devices because the devices LED or servo need to be updated of their LED brightness or servo position. If the servos need NOT be updated, say Servo 1 need duty cycle 50%, Servo 2 30%,  and so on. Then PCA9685 needs only go through the PWM channels only ONCE, then go to sleep forever.  The PWM channels will STAY at their assigned duty cycle, no need to update or refresh. Eg, for 100 servos at fixed duty cycle 5%, another 20 servos at 8%, just  two channels needed, one connected to 100 servos, another to 20 servos.

Comment: What you do may or may not be possible depending on **how** you plan to connect everything. Could you draw a circuit diagram?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that exactly, I would have just wired the actuators up to my servo driver. From what I undestand from @tifong01 's answer It should theoretically be possible to keep multiple of those in the same position, right? Is there a way of calculating how many are possible and how much voltage I need to supply in total?

Comment: I read the datasheet which shows each output driving a MOSFET which sinks one LED in series with a current limiting resistor, about 10mA.  I guess the gate current should be less than 1mA.  Now if I use my favourite power MOSFET IRx540N, with drain current bigger than 50A, then let me see how many LED or servo can I drive: 50A / 10mA == 5,000 LEDs or servos!  In other words, the max number of servos per channel is limited by the depth of your pocket! :)